# rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons in simple_form bootstrap not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

please forgive my newbieness here - I am trying to get the gem rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons to work in the rails app. I searched all over and can't figured it out. I have tried wrappers, but can't get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated!!

link to gem: https://github.com/caarlos0/rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons

link to gem source: https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch

I am trying to produce this:

```
<div class="switch" data-on="primary" data-off="info">
    <input type="checkbox" checked />
</div>
```

the code works great in the site but when I try to add it to simple_form then it goes down hill.

using Simple_forms :

= f.input :home_address

I had added :id=>"checkbox" and I have read the docs on the gem's site but I am very new at this and after 4 hours I am still not getting it
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you must have the `<div>` with the `data` attributes on your code. If you are putting just plain old `simple_form` code like `f.input`, it would just create the input, and not the wrapping `<div>` that carries the important stuff.